# React memcached-promisify TypeError: Stream is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, memcached

I'm trying to pull in data to a React solution based on [CoreUI](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template) from a remote memcached source using `memcached-promisify`.

To test at bare-bones, the following `test.js` returns an expected result with `node test.js`

```
const Cache = require('memcached-promisify');
const cache = new Cache({'cacheHost':'some.node:11211'});

cache.get('foo')
.then((r) => {
    console.log("Result: ", r);
}, (e) => {
    console.log("Error: ", e);
});
```

Console: `bar`

I then try to integrate it into the referenced React app Dashboard page as

```
const Cache = require('memcached-promisify');
const memcache = new Cache({'cacheHost':'some.node:11211'});

componentDidMount() {
    memcache.get('foo')
    .then((r) => {
        console.log("Result: ", r);
    }, (e) => {
        console.log("Error: ", e);
    });
}
```

and I'm given the following error in console:

```
creating memcached instance for cache host: some.node:11211
Dashboard.js:459 Error:  TypeError: Stream is not a constructor
at Manager.factory [as generator] (memcached.js:163)
at Manager.allocate (index.js:216)
at RetryOperation.attempt [as _fn] (index.js:129)
at ...
```

Feels like something fundamental in React I'm missing and I welcome learning.
Many thanks.

Comment: memcached-promisify is Node library and you're using it in browser, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

All credit to @estus - - simply wasn't thinking.